# Getting price from JSON

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get the JSON `key` and value called `price`. I can get the `key` but the price is just undefined.

```
    for(var item in prices.response){
        console.log(item);
        console.log(prices.response.price)
    }
```

Snippet of JSON

```
"response": {
    "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)": {
        "price": 962,
        "quantity": 192
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over object so `item` is name of object property not value. Try this

```
for(var key in prices.response){
    console.log(key);
    console.log(prices.response[key].price)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stick with your current code but you need to use `item` as your key like:

```
for(let item in prices.response){ // consider using let instead of var as well
    console.log(item);
    console.log(prices.response[item].price)
}
```

or you could go using directly the value as :

```
for(let item of prices.response){ // of keyword instead of in keyword
    console.log(item);
    console.log(item.price)
}
```